# Graph coloring connection-contraction

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I know that given a graph $G$ we can find its chromatic polynomial using the deletion-contraction algorithm as $P_G(k) = P_{G \setminus e}(k) - P_{G/e}(k)$.

Apparently there is an equivalent approach where in each step you take two non-adjacent vertices $u,v$ and we build two new graph, one with a new edge $e=(u,v)$ and another with the contraction of $u,v$ into a single vertex. Then we get that $P_G(k) = P_{G+e} + P_{G/e}$. Why are these two methods equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a graph which contains an edge $e$ and let $H = G\setminus e$; then we have

- $H+e = G$, and
- $H/e = G/e$.

Therefore $P_G = P_{G\setminus e} - P_{G/e}$ can be rewritten as $P_{H+e} = P_H - P_{H/e}$, or $P_H = P_{H+e} + P_{H/e}$, giving us the addition-identification rule.

Or do you mean "why do both methods work?" Addition-identification works because identifying two vertices makes the graph smaller, and adding edges eventually leads us to a complete graph, whose chromatic polynomial we know. To put it differently, both addition and identification reduce the number of edges in the complement graph - and we know what happens when that number is $0$.

Comment: I am saving two nitpicky and curmudgeonly opinions for the comments. First of all, the operation $H/e$ is no longer called "contraction", since you can only contract an edge. This is why the new recurrence is commonly called "addition-identification": in $H+e$, we add an edge, and in $H/e$, we identify two non-adjacent vertices.

Comment: Second, $G \setminus e$ and $G/e$ is terrible notation. Either we can use $G-e$ for the operation of deleting an edge (which is what I do even in other contexts), or we can use $G \mathbin{\bullet} e$ for the operation of contracting an edge, or both.